# Set up Scala for NetBeans - Error

Tags: scala, programming-languages, netbeans, compilation, environment-variables

I'm interested in the language Scala and would like to test it with NetBeans Can 6.8. I've downloaded Scala 2.8.0 final und unzipped it to my hard drive. Then I installed the Scala plugin for NetBeans and created a first project. Naturally compilation failed with this message:

> You must set `SCALA_HOME` or environment
>   property and append
>   "`-J-Dscala.home=scalahomepath`"
>                       property to the end of "`netbeans_default_options`" in
>   `NetBeansInstallationPath/etc/netbeans.conf`
>   to point to
>                       Scala installation directory.

I read what the NetBeans Wiki and the Scala website say to the plugin.

1. I've added a new environment variable `$SCALA_HOME` that points to `D:\Tools\scala-2.8.0.final`
2. I've added `$SCALA_HOME\bin` to my path variable
3. I've edited the `netbeans.conf` file by adding "`-J-Dscala.home=D:\Tools\scala-2.8.0.final`" to the end of netbeans_default_options

With your great help this error was fixed. However there are two new problems:

1. Code Completion doesn't work
   2.
2. After creating a Scala Object this

   ```
   package scalaapplication1


   object te {


   }
   ```

   is not accepted. NetBeans complains
   that

   > type ScalaObject is not a member of
   >   package Scala

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strange: the [Netbeans Wiki on Scala](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala68v1) doesn't mention "`scala.home`", only the environment variable `SCALA_HOME`.

So does the tutorial on [Scala plugin installation](http://pierre8r.blogspot.com/2009/09/installing-scala-plugin-for-netbeans-on.html):

[image]

---

After that, you need to make sure Netbeans is **launched from a new dos session (one that has registered the new environment variable definition)**, and is "path-aware" (like this [issue 175394](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=175394), even though it only concerns Unix platform).

---

[DarrenWang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497905/darrenwang) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100481/set-up-scala-for-netbeans-error/4102867#4102867) in [his article](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zeuux.com%2Fgroup%2Fscalaba%2Fbbs%2Fcontent%2F4240%2F) the [NBModules plugins](http://nbmodules.javaforge.com/) to more easily manage those options like "`-J-Dscala.home = scalahomepath`" in the `netbeans.conf` file.
But it experienced some crashed with the Scala plugin and the latest Netbeans.

Comment: I've deleted the $ sign in front of SCALA_HOME. Now NetBeans compiles the project. Nevertheless I still don't understand what has just happened. I feel like I ought to import some standard jar for Scala or set up some library dependencies. However there's no compiler error. Is this the standard way ? Just add some environment variables ?

Comment: I just realized that Code Completion doesn't work. What do I need to change ?

Comment: @lhk: if you did have created an environment variable named `$SCALA_HOME`, that would have been the cause of the initial problem: `$SCALA_HOME` is for getting the *value* of the variable name `SCALA_HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you read Chinese? hehe, I wrote down something here:
http://www.zeuux.com/group/scalaba/bbs/content/4240/